# Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.V2.dll location

Tags: ecl, sites-9.1, ecl-connector

I am trying to create custom ECL connector for Tridion 9.1 and Widen DAM system.
To do that I need to create a .NET solution where i need to put `Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.V2.dll` references as i have learnt from blogs.
Please let me know from where i can get that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

%TRIDION_HOME%bin\client

Default location for %TRIDION_HOME$ is C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL\Tridion Sites\

But if you are using Tridion Sites 9.1 you should use latest V3 dll (in same folder)